# What is the meaning of different integer mysql types

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

What is the difference between, for example, TINYINT and INT(1) or between TINYINT(3) and MEDIUMINT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the storage.

`TINYINT` is a 1 byte. `MEDIUMINT` is 3 bytes. `INT` is 4 bytes.
`TINYINT(3)` 3 here is the display width. Display width is unrelated to the range of values a type can contain.

So `TINYINT` and `TINYINT(3)` takes the same storage, but presentation is different.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports the SQL standard integer types INTEGER (or INT) and SMALLINT. As an extension to the standard, MySQL also supports the integer types TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, and BIGINT. The following table shows the required storage and range for each integer type.

[image]

Refer their main [website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: I've already read it before asking question! :) The point is that size of field could be set manually and not really depends on type, is it?

Comment: If you will use say "Tinyint" data type for your field, then if try to enter data outside its range, the data will be converted to a value within range. So what I think is that data type selection matters as per your requirements.

Comment: Oh, I've just find answer myself!
If someone interesting: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Comment: The size field is used only for `ZEROFILL`.

Answer (score 0):

INT - A normal-sized integer that can be signed or unsigned. If signed, the allowable range is from -2147483648 to 2147483647. If unsigned, the allowable range is from 0 to 4294967295. You can specify a width of up to 11 digits.

TINYINT - A very small integer that can be signed or unsigned. If signed, the allowable range is from -128 to 127. If unsigned, the allowable range is from 0 to 255. You can specify a width of up to 4 digits.

SMALLINT - A small integer that can be signed or unsigned. If signed, the allowable range is from -32768 to 32767. If unsigned, the allowable range is from 0 to 65535. You can specify a width of up to 5 digits.

MEDIUMINT - A medium-sized integer that can be signed or unsigned. If signed, the allowable range is from -8388608 to 8388607. If unsigned, the allowable range is from 0 to 16777215. You can specify a width of up to 9 digits.

BIGINT - A large integer that can be signed or unsigned. If signed, the allowable range is from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807. If unsigned, the allowable range is from 0 to 18446744073709551615. You can specify a width of up to 20 digits.

FLOAT(M,D) - A floating-point number that cannot be unsigned. You can define the display length (M) and the number of decimals (D). This is not required and will default to 10,2, where 2 is the number of decimals and 10 is the total number of digits (including decimals). Decimal precision can go to 24 places for a FLOAT.

DOUBLE(M,D) - A double precision floating-point number that cannot be unsigned. You can define the display length (M) and the number of decimals (D). This is not required and will default to 16,4, where 4 is the number of decimals. Decimal precision can go to 53 places for a DOUBLE. REAL is a synonym for DOUBLE.

DECIMAL(M,D) - An unpacked floating-point number that cannot be unsigned. In unpacked decimals, each decimal corresponds to one byte. Defining the display length (M) and the number of decimals (D) is required. NUMERIC is a synonym for DECIMAL.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.htm

Comment: `FLOAT/DOUBLE(M,N)` should "never" be used.  Only use `FLOAT/DOUBLE`.

Answer (score 0):

> MySQL supports an extension for optionally specifying the display width of integer data types in parentheses following the base keyword for the type. For example, INT(4) specifies an INT with a display width of four digits. This optional display width may be used by applications to display integer values having a width less than the width specified for the column by left-padding them with spaces. (That is, this width is present in the metadata returned with result sets. Whether it is used or not is up to the application.)
>
> The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column display width from being displayed correctly. For example, a column specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to 32767, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are displayed in full using more than three digits.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-attributes.html